# Python: groupby, create new column based on max value of other column

Tags: python, pandas

Hi guys I have the following question:

I have a dataframe (df) that looks like:

```
user_id    datetime    
1          00:00:01     
1          00:00:03
1          00:00:10
2          00:00:05
2          00:00:07
3          00:00:09
```

I want to add a new column to this called: ['yesno'] with values 1 or 0 based on the following ruling. For every unique user_id I want only the latest (or highest) datetime to get the value 1 in column ['yesno'], the other values (lower than the maximum datetime value) should get the value 0.

Is there any quick way to this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use `s = df.groupby("user_id")["datetime"].transform('max')
df["yesno"]= s.eq(df["datetime"]).astype(int)`

Comment: Also first step should be `df["datetime"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["datetime"])`

Comment: thanks a lot jezrael!